# Where does Conda save the compiled libraries associated with Conda environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've written an Apache Spark python script, and for compatibility reasons I need to pass a specific version of scikit-learn when I submit the Spark job to the cluster. The problem is I'm not sure where I can get a copy of the scikit-learn binary/executable that I need. I don't think it's as straight forward as downloading the scikit-learn source and compiling myself because I've heard scikit-learn has a lot of dependencies, and I'm not sure which dependencies I need for the version I require. I was thinking I could create a Conda environment with the specific scikit-learn version I need so that Conda could do all the compiling for me, but I'm not sure where Conda saves the libraries that it builds. I tried checking under the default venv folder, but didn't see anything promising.

Answer (score 2):

Conda takes care of the dependencies.  Just pass the version to Conda:

```
$ conda install scikit-learn=0.16.1
```

If you want the exact version of every package, you can do the following:

```
$ conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

You then create a new environment as follows:

```
$ conda create -n my_environment --file requirements.txt
```

Comment: I'm able to install the correct versions of my dependencies in Conda without trouble, the problem is I'm not sure where the files corresponding to those dependencies are stored. I was hoping to pull the dependency files out of Conda so that I could use them in a totally different place (e.g. on a Hadoop cluster where I won't have access to my Conda environment directly). I'd like to ship the Conda dependency files with one of my Hadoop jobs

Comment: In any case I'm not sure if you actually would be able to reliably move binary files installed by conda to a completely different system. I don't understand the details myself, but this is maybe helpful: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#making-packages-relocatable

Answer (score 0):

Packages are stored in the `(prefix)/pkgs` folder, before being extracted.  Extracted files can live lots of places in the prefix - just whatever the package specifies.  You can ship the package tarballs around if necessary, and install from them directly (specify them as arguments `conda install`).  However, it really is nicer to do what Alexander suggested here: create a requirements file that pins versions.  You should also look into using conda-env.  It gives more flexibility in terms of obtaining packages from anaconda.org than the plain requirements file obtained from conda list.

Docs on conda-env: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html